# Get Struts request parameter without key

Tags: java, servlets, struts, struts-1

Let's say I have the following URL:

> http://example.com/myvariable1

What is the best way to get access to myvariable1 in Struts 1.x?

Alternative - add a parameter to the variable:

> http://example.com/mykey=myvariable1

I found a similar question that solves this with a parameter, however, I would very much like a solution that can let me get this implicitly.

[Can't get request attribute in struts action class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897227/cant-get-request-attribute-in-struts-action-class)

Comment: request.getParameterValues(); returns map of parameters if you don't want to query by parameter.

Comment: @thinksteep: java.lang.String[] getParameterValues(java.lang.String s); It still needs a parameter key.

Comment: Sorry! my mistake. Check if getParameterMap() is available. This is what I meant.

Answer (score -2):

Struts1 doesn't offer anything to help for that except the standard Servlet API. You'll need to use the methods from `HttpServletRequest` class to get this information, for example [getRequestURI()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29).

Struts1 is completely obsolete. You would get better support from more modern frameworks like Stripes, Spring MVC, Play, etc.